# How to find all .sh files and make them executable using bash in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

also when I launch I want to pass path to folder when located these .sh files

I started with this

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/user_name -name "*.sh"
```

And after script has to write in logo list with executable files

Answer (score 22):

The safest and way both in terms of security and in terms of weird file names (spaces, weird characters, and so forth) is to use `find` directly:

```
find /home/user -name "*.sh" -execdir chmod u+x {} +
```

You can check the comments and the manual of find why this is safe, but in short, it makes sure your file is properly quoted in the `chmod` command. `execdir` (rather then `-exec`) is an extra security feature making sure the command is executed in the directory the file was found in avoiding race conditions (elaborated in the manual).

Comment: May I ask why is the 2nd one "very unsafe"?

Comment: Exactly, @hek2mgl.

Comment: @hek2mgl For posterior: pointed out another solution now removed is unsafe since argument expansion fails on file names with spaces: passing `$()` the argument list to `chmod`.

Comment: Just one thing about the `-execdir`. In this case it doesn't make a difference because `chmod` will have no side-effects except from changing the file permissions of the target file. It would make a difference if you, let's say, going to execute the scripts `find` detects. In that case the working dir of those scripts when using `-exec` would be the directory where you execute `find` from. If now two scripts try something like `if [ -f lock.file ] ;` (meaning they try to access relative paths) then both would try to work on the same file instead of a file called lock.file in their directory

Comment: So why use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`? `execdir` results in just the filenames with paths stripped off, so in my case it ends up looking for all the files in the top level directory find was executed from, resulting in `chmod script.sh: No such file or directory` because that script is actually down a couple levels.

Comment: @ScottyC I'm not sure what you mean. `execdir` just executes the command in the directory it was found, with the file as an argument, instead of executing it relative to the original directory you ran `find`. This avoids several security issues that are mentioned in the `man` and around the internet. If you feel it's unclear that would warrant a question on SO, but research first. If the command you're running explicitly depends on being run from the original `find` directory (which is odd, and probably not a best choice of design) then it would obviously fail.

Comment: Oh wow, I just tired it on Linux, you're right it works just fine. Looks like its just the FreeBSD version of find (I'm on a Mac) doesn't work correctly ending the command with `... {} +`, you have to use `... {} \;`

I found that line ending in another example using `-exec` that worked for me and I incorrectly assumed the problem was execdir. Still not sure why this odd behavior occurs for this BSD find with that `+` though...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make all files executable for the current user, you can use the command as follows (assuming that you have permission for all files in target home folder) :

```
find /home/user_name -name "*.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 chmod u+x
```

Comment: Don't use `xargs` if you don't understand the consequences. `find` has `-exec`. Use it!

Comment: @hek2mgl What would be the consequences here?

Comment: `xargs` performs word splitting and filenames on UNIX may contain spaces.

Comment: Ok, you use a null byte as the delimiter now. Good. Now please tell me one advantage over using `-exec`?

Comment: @hek2mgl just something alternative and suitable for all kind of commands beyond `find`

Comment: ... any command that supports null byte separation ;) Well, some do. Especially GNU tools. Anyhow, imo `find -exec` is the way to go here.

Comment: @Akif is it possible to add how you could also execute all the scripts as well?

Comment: @Akif ....and as a side note I am asking how _would you add the execution command to your command_?

Answer (score 1):

another way :

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod ux+y {} \;
```

you can first check your command by using

```
find . -name "*.sh" -print
```

Answer (score -1):

By @kabanus command

```
#!/bin/bash

# chmod u+x $(find $1 -name "*.sh")
# ls -1 $1/*.sh
find $1 -name "*.sh" -print -exec chmod u+x {} +
```

And use as

```
$ ./script.sh /your_directory
```

`/your_directory` - first argument (`$1`) in the script.

Comment: a) don't copy b) don't copy things you don't understand and which are wrong!

Comment: I changed my answer. And I just want to help @ASdsdgf.

Comment: Your help doesn't help. You are just duplicating content. Stop that or you'll get flagged.

Comment: @hek2mgl Read the question and you will understand that I am trying to help in the solution.